# How to pass both column name and column datatype to toDF() function

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

How can we pass both column name and column datatype to `toDF()` function?

Something like,

```
df.rdd.map(lambda x: (x.col1, x.col2, x.col3)).toDF('col1:string, col2:int, col3:boolean')
```

Comment: why are you doing this? are you just trying to cast the column types?

Comment: No, I'm performing some transformations and changing the column type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `spark.createDataFrame` with the transformed RDD and provide a schema:

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    df.rdd.map(lambda x: (x.col1, x.col2, x.col3)), 
    'col1:string, col2:int, col3:boolean'
)
```